# Fresh Linux (Debian and CentOS) installation will not boot

Tags: linux, boot, partition, system-installation, boot-loader

I am trying to install either Debian or CentOS on a home server (Fujitsu PRIMERGY TX100 S3).  I first tried installing Debian.  The whole installation was successful (including grub).  But after rebooting, the OS would not boot up. My partition was the default setting for new users:

```
/dev/sda1 primary
/dev/sda5 logical (swap)
```

After booting, it gets to Intel Boot Agent and says it can't boot from media.  I even tried disabling the DVD drive as a boot option.  There is another device listed in boot options but the name is so ambiguous (IBA GE Slot 0200 v1372), I don't even know for sure if it refers to the hard drive.

I then tried CentOS, and the same problem occurred.  I have looked around this website, some other StackExchange websites, and also general internet searching, and it seems that my problem is related to the boot process.

My problem is that I just don't know exactly where to begin looking.  This is my first time setting up a Linux OS on a physical machine.  Am I correct in assuming it is not reaching the BootLoader program properly?  Or could this problem be caused by other things (ie, hardware)?

Comment: Sounds stupid, but make sure you're installing the bootloader to `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm new to this. So it's a valid point to bring up.  I actually tried manually installing the bootloader to `/dev/sda1`after it was not successful with `/dev/sda`.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to '@' this guy while replying .. but anyway , did you choose to boot from HDD ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable RAID controller in Advanced BIOS configuration and use standard AHCI or IDE SATA controller. This could help - from the boot menu there's more option including booting from disks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a special driver for the hard disk.

If I google "Fujitsu PRIMERGY TX100 S3 CentOS" the first hit is [a link to a whitepaper on CentOS on this server](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.ts.fujitsu.com%2Fcommunity-linux%2Fcentos%2FTR-PY-TX100-S3-CentOS.pdf&ei=3iCdT47cHsOU-wa798nwDg&usg=AFQjCNHlF69ktklzGPzJBjSsN_Tz66EE0A).